# How to insert into table the results of a dynamic query when the schema of the result is unknown a priori?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Observe the following simple SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (...) -- Here comes the schema
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC(@Sql)              -- The @Sql is a dynamic query generating result with a known schema
```

All is good, because we know the schema of the result produced by `@Sql`.

But what if the schema is unknown? In this case I use Powershell to generate a Sql query like that:

```
SET @Sql = '
SELECT *
INTO ##MySpecialAndUniquelyNamedGlobalTempTable
FROM ($Query) x
'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

(I omit some details, but the "spirit" of the code is preserved)

And it works fine, except that there is a severe limitation to what `$Query` can be - it must be a single `SELECT` statement.

This is not very good for me, I would like to be able to run any Sql script like that. The problem, is that no longer can I concatenate it to `FROM (`, it must be executed by `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`. But then I have no idea how to collect the results into a table, because I have no idea of the schema of that table.

Is it possible in Sql Server 2012?

**Motivation:** We have many QA databases across different Sql servers and more often than not I find myself running queries on all of them in order to locate the database most likely to yield best results for my tests. Alas, I am only able to run single SELECT statements, which is inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

We use SP and OPENROWSET for this purpose.

At first create SP based on a query you need, than use OPENROWSET to get data into temp table:

```
USE Test

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @query nvarchar(max)

SET @sql = N'Some query'

IF OBJECT_ID(N'SomeSPname') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE SomeSPname

SET @query =N'
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeSPname
AS
BEGIN
    '+@sql+'
END'

EXEC sp_executesql @query

USE tempdb
IF OBJECT_ID(N'#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM OPENROWSET(
               'SQLNCLI',
               'Server=SERVER\INSTANCE;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
               'EXEC dbo.SomeSPname')

SELECT *
FROM #temp
```